# Flutter app behaving unexpectedly on Oppo A31

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

Home screen view on the different phone responding in a different manner. As you can see the attached screenshots, its working fine on all iOS devices but in android it working on pixel but in oppo, the screen turns to grey.

[image: iPhone home screen]
[image: Google pixel home screen]
[image: Oppo home screen]

Comment: maybe use oppo phone to debug?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use Oppo for debugging? Did the code execute as desired? Is it app-release that is not working or app-debug? And are there any unconventional plugins?

Comment: No I don't have the oppo phone with me, It a bug reported by the user, The grey screen blocked the user from further interactions with the application, app-release is not working as I provided them a release version, I am not cleared with the last point.

Comment: @KanwarpreetSingh did you resolved the issue?